# Error 403 when trying to connect to websocket api

Tags: unificationengine

I currently develop a realtime kik connector for the unification engine.
To receive the messages, I connect to the websocket endpoint using my users name and password.
Sadly, I get an error 403 everytime.
Is there anything else I have to look out for?

Some examples:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/connection/list -u $USER_NAME:$PASSWORD --data "{}" -k -s | jq
{
  "status": 200,
  "info": "200 OK",
  "connections": {
    "kik": {
      "uri": "kik://kik_user@kik.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Websocket:

```
$ wscat --auth "$USER_NAME:$PASSWORD" -c wss://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/ws/start

error: Error: unexpected server response (403)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using this library?
https://github.com/websockets/wscat

Does this library support authentication in this way?

wscat --auth "$USER_NAME:$PASSWORD" -c wss://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/ws/start

Done research on this, wscat is using npm ws, https://github.com/websockets/ws for webscoket connection.

Can you try header like this and check

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/ws/start', {
    origin: 'https://apiv2.unificationengine.com',
    headers: { Authorization: 'base64 auth' }
});
```

You can create base64 auth like this in nodejs

var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(USER_ACCESS_KEY + ":" + USER_ACCESS_SECRET).toString("base64");

Comment: Ok thanks this solved the problem. It's a little bit strange because `wscat` uses the exactly same code to generate Authorization headers: https://github.com/websockets/wscat/blob/master/bin/wscat#L189

Comment: After some more research I now fully understand the problem. The api does not accept calls without the `origin` header. When using `wscat` you have to set the `--origin` option

Comment: @Martin I am using unification API but getting 403 error. Can u guide me that how to send access token within Curl.